# Spring : Using @Value for a non String property

Tags: java, spring

I have this,

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:abc.properties")
public class AbcConfig {

  @Value("${test.testLogger}")
  private Logger logger;

  @Bean
  public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertyConfigIn() {
    return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
  }
```

and then in my java code, I was hoping to pass in the Logger for that class in when creating the AnnotationContext using Properties,

```
context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
Properties prop = new Properties();
prop.put("test.testLogger", getLogger());
context.getEnvironment().getPropertySources().addLast(new PropertiesPropertySource("test", prop));
context.register(AbcConfig.class);
context.refresh();
```

Unfortunately, when i run this i get the following exception,

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot convert value [org.apache.log4j.Logger@5f015823] from source type [Logger] to target type [String]
at org.springframework.core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver.getProperty(PropertySourcesPropertyResolver.java:84)
at org.springframework.core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver.getProperty(PropertySourcesPropertyResolver.java:59)
at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractEnvironment.getProperty(AbstractEnvironment.java:427)
at org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer$1.getProperty(PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.java:131)
at org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer$1.getProperty(PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.java:128)
at org.springframework.core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver.getProperty(PropertySourcesPropertyResolver.java:73)
at org.springframework.core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver.getProperty(PropertySourcesPropertyResolver.java:59)
at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver$1.resolvePlaceholder(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:176)
at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.parseStringValue(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:146)
at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.replacePlaceholders(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:125)
at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.doResolvePlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:174)
at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.resolveRequiredPlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:143)
at org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer$2.resolveStringValue(PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.java:167)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveEmbeddedValue(AbstractBeanFactory.java:755)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:778)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:768)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:486)
... 32 more
```

So it seems to me like the use of @Value is only applicable for String (and maybe Integer). 
this is using Spring 3.2.2.
Is there a workaround for this (to use Logger or any other non-string objects)?

Comment: @ Value works for strings. Its  a property reader. If you want object of Logger type, use @ Autowired. You can configure bean in the main application class. Read https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html for more help

Comment: Why do you want to use `@Value` for`Logger` ?